# find span in element using id

Tags: jquery, html, find, clone

this is confusing me why this does not work?
I have a group of HTML that I clone several times in a page, and it looks like this:

```html
<span id="v3_configuration_parameter_value_prototype" class="configurationParameterValue" style="display: none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="configurationParameterValues_id" />

    <span id="v3_0label" style="display:none;"><label>Signed Integer From</label></span>
    <span id="v3_1label" style="display:none;"><label>Unsigned Integer From</label></span>
    <span id="to_box" style="display:inline;">
        <label>To</label>
            <input type="text" name="configurationParameterValues_to" size="3" />
    </span>
    <input type="hidden" name="configurationParameters_type" value="0" />
       <a onclick="remove_configuration_parameter_value(this);">Remove</a>
    <br />
</span>
```

I make a clone of the code:

```js
var newValue = $("#v3_configuration_parameter_value_prototype").clone();
```

But when I try to reference it to hide/unhide it using this line, it fails saying it cannot find it.

```js
$(newValue).find("span[id='to_box']").style.display = 'inline';
```

I am setting it before I add it to the page where there will be duplicates, so I need to set it within the newValue code.

Comment: IDs can't be reused on a page - they're meant to be unique. Can you make these classes instead?

Comment: They are re-used on the page, but at this point in the code the HTML snippet is standalone and not a part of the page, so there are no duplicates.  If I change the ID to Class, how do I find that class in the code snippet newValue?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: jQuery uses CSS-style selectors to find elements - IDs use `#` and classes use `.` - so you'd look for `$('.classname')`

Comment: Sorry for being obtuse - playing with the code like this is new to me as I inherited the code.  In my case, would it be this:  $(newValue).('.classname').style.display='whatever';

Comment: Quick update - tried this also and it did not work:
$(newValue).children('.v3_0label').style.display = 'inline';

Comment: Found it!  $(newValue).find(".to_box").hide();  - using Style.Display = 'value' was also not correct.